# How to analyse Websphere core*.dmp file and Snap*.trc files?

Tags: java, websphere-7, coredump, analyzer, heap-dump

All,
I have my application running on websphere app server 7.0.
I get some of these core dumps and trace files like

core.20110909.164930.3828.0001.dmp

and

Snap.20110909.164930.3828.0003.trc.

My question is, just like the thread dumps generated by WAS can be opened and analyzed by [IBM-Thread Dump Analyzer tool](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/jca/download)

is there a tool(s) to open the above mentioned files by IBM or any other?

Thanks,
Ayusman

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the core dumps have to be processed by the jextract utility (of the jre that dumped)
fromn my webspere root this is ./java/jre/bin/jextract.

The resulting output can then be proccessed by ISA

Snap files are proccessed by the java trace tool ie 
java com.ibm.jvm.format.TraceFormat  [] [options]
from 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/realtime/v1r0/topic/com.ibm.rt.doc.10/diag/tools/trace_formatter.html  for was v6

the output is readable

mike prendergast

Comment: Where is the TraceFormat for was8 ? I don't see any information for that version.

Comment: Link didn't work for me, but 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.win.70.doc/diag/tools/trace_formatter.html had what I needed

Answer (score 7):

[Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) is an excellent tool for analyzing the core*.dmp (and portable heap dumps, i.e. .phd files, too). To read those Websphere Dumps an additional plugin called [IBM Diagnostic Tool Framework for Java](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/dtfj.html) needs to be installed ([Update Site](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/runtimes/tools/dtfj/)).

Before even trying to open big dumps remember to increase the tool's heap size by modifying the `MemoryAnalyzer.ini` and adding/modifying the line

`-Xmx4096m`

Adjust this number to your needs.